# Function to terminate while loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I would like to create a function `keep_running` that I could define based on input to either be sensitive to the time that it had been running or the number of iterations. I can't seem to come up with a pythonic way to do the iterations without decrementing the counter outside of the function, e.g.:

```
def keep_running(ttl):
    return ttl > 0

ttl = 1
while keep_running(ttl):
    do_stuff()
    ttl -= 1
```

Is there a better way to do this, preferably completely within the function `keep_running`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to manage state is probably inside a class.  You could initialize an object `loop_context` with a `ttl` value, and then your loop condition would be `loop_context.keep_running()`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure about your demand. But iterator might useful for you. Use a iterator, it could be:

```
>>> def keep_running(ttl):
    while ttl>0:
        yield ttl
        ttl -= 1
>>> for one_round in keep_running(3):
    print(time.time())
```

Result is:

```
1365464545.465
1365464545.495
1365464545.505
```